# Is it possible to avoid port 8080 in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using port 8080 in node js to connect Linux machines and get the data. My firewall indicates below security issues.

```
WEB-ATTACKS GNU Bash Code Injection (CVE-2014-6271)
```

It means port 8080 is open and somebody can easily hack the server. Is it possible? If yes then how can we avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend for your web server to be accessible to the outside world and have enabled access through your firewall (or other network infrastructure from the outside world to your server) to allow external agents to connect to your server on that specific port, then the port number you use does not make your server more of less hackable.  port 8080 has no more or less security risks than port 80 or any other port for that matter.

Whether your server is hackable or not depends upon the security design of your actual server process and what vulnerabilities it does or doesn't have that can be exploited by hackers (which is completely independent of which port it operates on) and on what other ports on your server you are allowing potential attackers to access and try to get into.

If you want further help, you will have to explain more about what "My firewall indicates it has some security issues" means.  Exactly what is being reported by your firewall?  What security issues?

Comment: " WEB-ATTACKS GNU Bash Code Injection (CVE-2014-6271)" this message from firewall.

Comment: jfriend, how to avoid this message from firewall?

Comment: @selvan - Did you search for that specific vulnerability to understand it?  As I read [here](https://www.mysonicwall.com/sonicalert/searchresults.aspx?ev=article&id=731), it doesn't seem to apply to node.js.  It could apply to Apache in some circumstances.  If this is really your question, why didn't you put this exact info and your exact question in your question?

Comment: @selvan - To understand how to get your firewall to stop talking about that vulnerability, you need to first makes sure you are patched vs. that vulnerability and then search for info about your firewall and that specific vulnerability.  You don't disclose any info about your firewall so nothing we can do to help you with that side of things.

Comment: @selvan - More info about protecting from that vulnerability: https://security.berkeley.edu/news/shellshock-gnu-bash-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-cve-2014-6271

Comment: Also tell me, how can we use node js without 8080 port?

Comment: @selvan - You can run your web server on any port you want, but it has to be on some port and you have to allow traffic on that port through your firewall to reach your server.  The specific vulnerability you mention has nothing to do with port 8080.

Comment: thanks @jfriiend..

Comment: @selvan - Did this answer your question?  If it did, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn your some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.